# How does elixir performs slicing

Tags: linked-list, erlang, elixir, immutability, beam

I m starting to work with elixir, doing some experiments with Enum module. How does slicing operation on list gets performed? If the slice is applied from any node to the last one, it s intuitive (I guess). Instead if I slice until an item that is not the last one , does it create a new copy? Or does it track the size? I d like to know how elixir lists works under the hood(not basic information, I know it s just a singly linked list)... if you have any source  that gives more detail on that or anybody would be so patient to explain me I will enjoy it

Thank you in advance

Comment: The [tag:elixir] implementation [delegates](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.16.0/lib/elixir/lib/enum.ex#L4499) to [tag:erlang] on the list representation level. Everything else is available from the answer I used to close this question as duplicate.